# Unreadable barcode scanned by barcode reader

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I am a developer and i am making an app to read the electricity bill information. I have bought a good barcode scanner 'symbol ls2208'. It is scanning barcode but it returns an unrecognized string consists of alphabets,numbers and symbols. It should return the string written under the barcode.

Please have a look at this screenshot

[image]

in the screenshot the barcode scanner should return the string 'feb 19 ....' but it is returning the string 'L000AjZmqOp24dI7x]K000002J13J#'

i have checked the barcode online and this barcode reading site https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/
is confirming that it is code 128, i have checked code 128 and tried to decrypt this 'strange' string but it is not converting to 'feb 19 ...' can anyone please help me ?

Please note: I have checked other bills too and other medicine products barcodes and they are returning what is written under 'barcode'.

Comment: If other bill barcodes are returning the text underneath then perhaps the barcode is malformed.  My first thought given the context of your question was perhaps the barcode was encoded UDI but that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: @DarrynCampbell i tried today zxing library with android app and it is returning required results. I have enabled code 128 mode in my barcode reader but still it is returning unreadable results.

Comment: My reader gives exact the same code, so barcode reading is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The barcode clearly does not encode the string that is written underneath it.  It encodes what your scanner decodes.  I verified that with scanners over here.